# Nginx: cross domain redirection is not working for angular app

Tags: angular, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have angular app on my prod environment. it has domain url like i.e. **https://abc.test.com/test?tag=Canada**, this is loading angular application.

Below are the nginx config: This is working fine.

```
location /test{
        
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';   
                
            alias         testapp/;
            try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /test/index.html;

           autoindex off;
        }
```

---

Now there is a need where I need to provide access of same deployed angular app access via diff domain URL and pattern. i.e.
https://abc.test.com/test?tag=Canada
to
https://abc.test.com/Canada

I did below settings into nginx but its giving some error:
**nginx config:**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost abc.test.com;
    
     location / {
        proxy_pass https://abc.test.com;
        rewrite /(.*)$ /test?id=$1 break;
    }
}
```

**error:**
Nginx reverse proxy giving Error: SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState'
**main.8b0f03ac4d5a39ba.js:1 Unhandled Navigation Error: SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'https://abc.test.com/test/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://abc.test.com' and URL 'http://abc.test.com/Canada'.**

Thank you for help in advance.